# VBS Regex getting the underscore from a string

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have a simple outcome to detect part of a file name. My files have their general name (FILENAME), a second name (SECONDNAME#) and a final tag, all links by underscores.

I am after the second name, which can have a small number of values. The third part, the final tag, can be highly variable and is not checked for.

FILENAME_SECONDNAME1_DS.txt

FILENAME_SECONDNAME2_DS.txt

FILENAME_SECONDNAME3_ER.txt

Detecting the trailing underscore after teh second name is important to help indicate I have the second name and are not accidentally detecting a similar string part in the filename.

I check with the following

```
set RE = new RegExp
RE.Ignorecase = true

sCONST = "FILENAME_SECONDNAME1_DS.txt"

RE.pattern = "(SECONDNAME1)|(SECONDNAME2)|(SECONDNAME3)_"
if RE.test(sCONST) = true then
    set matches = RE.Execute(sCONST)
    for each match in matches
        MsgBox match.Value
    next
end if
```

VB's RegExp matches my pattern but match.Value never has the underscore. I can only assume I am not matching the underscore with my pattern. How can I get the underscore included in my matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe works on the whole thing, so with your current regex, the 3 possible alternatives are `SECONDNAME1`, `SECONDNAME2`, and `SECONDNAME3_`.

That being said, you don't even need the pipe operator in this case.

Do the following instead:

`SECONDNAME[1-3]_`

Just match `SECONDNAME` followed by either 1, 2, or 3, which is then followed by an underscore.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1RiXZW/5)

Answer (score 1):

You can build your pattern into groups in order to gain access them easily after :

***[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/X5rWtF/1)*** `^(\w+_)(\w+_)(.*)(\.txt)$`

```
Set RE = new RegExp
RE.Ignorecase = True
RE.global = True
RE.MultiLine = True
RE.pattern = "^(\w+_)(\w+_)(.*)(\.txt)$"

sCONST = "FILENAME_SECONDNAME1_DS.txt" & vbCrlf &_
"FILENAME_SECONDNAME2_DS.txt" & vbCrlf &_
"FILENAME_SECONDNAME3_DS.txt" & vbCrlf &_
"FILENAME_SECONDNAME4_DS.txt" & vbCrlf &_
"FILENAME_SECONDNAME5_ER.txt" & vbCrlf &_
"FILENAME_SECONDNAME6_ER.txt"

If RE.test(sCONST) = True then
    Set matches = RE.Execute(sCONST)
    For Each match in matches
        MsgBox "The first group is : "& match.subMatches(0) & vbCrlf & _
        "The second group is : "& match.subMatches(1) & vbCrlf & _
        "The third group is : "& match.subMatches(2) & vbCrlf & _
        "The fourth group is : "& match.subMatches(3)
    Next
End if
```